# BlueJ Image Not Found

Tags: java, javafx, bluej

I have a JavaFX BlueJ project. Following is the simple directory structure

[image: Project Structure]

As you can see that I have a `Gui.java` and `map.png` files in same directory. Following is my code

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Dragon Castle");

    Game game = new Game();
    TextArea logArea = new TextArea();

    VBox vbox = new VBox(10);

    // Create maps

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(770, 630);

    Image map = new Image("map.png"); // Here it is giving error

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // Insert controls

    VBox controlsVbox = new VBox(5);
    controlsVbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    HBox buttonHboxR1 = new HBox(5);
    buttonHboxR1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); .... Other code
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$7/22058848.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1099)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:608)
    at src.Gui.start(Gui.java:46)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$57/5668924.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$53/812813.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$55/19277439.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$54/26973244.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$43/21354624.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1091)
    ... 16 more
```

Image not found. I tried same code in eclipse, its working. Also I put `map.png` in resources folder but its still not working in BlueJ.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Image` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the
>   passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is
>   searched on the classpath in that case.

So, since you pass a simple path, the `Image` constructor will attempt to resolve that relative to the classpath. Looking at the stack trace, your `Gui` class appears to be in a package called `src` (really???) and your image is in the same package. Hence the path to the image should be `src/map.png`.

A better way to retrieve the image from the same package as the current class is to get the URL from the class object as a resource:

```
Image map = new Image(getClass().getResource("map.png").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: If this still gives you errors, you should check the build folder (not the source folder) actually contains the image in the expected location. I have no knowledge of BlueJ so I don't know how you would configure that.

Comment: Well I tried your code. Its not working. In `bin` folder (all the class files) and `map.png` are there.

Comment: @Junaid So in `bin` you have `src/Gui.class` and `src/map.png`? I don't understand why there are `.java` files and `.class` files in the same folder in your screenshot.

Comment: Well yes, actually BlueJ converted eclipse javaFx project to this one.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("Gui.class"));` give you? (I am assuming the code you posted is in `Gui.java`...)

Comment: Its giving me `SimpleGui/src/Gui.class`

Comment: Presumably it is really giving you something like `file:/folder/subfolder/.../SimpleGui/src/Gui.class`. So it's running from a folder called `SimpleGui`, I guess? Do you have `SimpleGui/src/map.png`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132312/discussion-between-junaid-and-james-d).

Comment: @James_D BlueJ doesn't have a dedicated build folder per say, so it keeps .class and .java files in the same folder

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Sounds like a good reason never, ever, to use BlueJ...